# Using adaptor vs proxy for integration with multiple providers

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm going to integrate with more than one provider and each one have different interface, so I have 2 options and want to chose one of them:

1- using adaptor so inside my application will have interface contains all methods with parameters I'm expecting, and when get provider API will make adaptor for this API by implementing the interface from my application.

2- using universal proxy proxy implement specific interface "could be the interface specified in adaptor option" and this proxy will have to call provider API and provide the methods for my application to use it

Note 1: you may think that 2 options are the same but it is not, in adaptor you are expecting that the provider api will have same methods you have in different names and same parameters but may be will need to be cast, in proxy you have more flexibility from the side of provider so provider can be what ever java api, REST service or anything else.

Note 2: the contract between me and provider api in option 1 is business common understanding, but in option 2 it is code interface have to be implemented

Note 3: I can have both in one solution, proxy inside my application and use adaptor to call provider API and if provider API is not matching our Business common understanding will make another proxy over it like :

```
Provider => proxy => adaptor => proxy
```

but do I need that rather than using only proxy to wrap all of this?

Comment: Do you need to take the decision now? As far as I understood the most important thing is to decouple your code from the APIs you will consume (which you already did through an interface - facade?). That will allow you to defer the decision till the point you know how the one "on the works" looks and apply the best design that fits at that time

Comment: More details (code examples) will allow a clearer answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the **proxy** pattern is not intended to adapt an expected interface to another. It is to say, Proxy pattern is intended to solve a problem related with :

- Accessing a remote interface
- Accessing a costly/complex interface

Both cases, proxy easy interface access.

On the other hand, you have **adapter** pattern that is intended for adapt a real interface to a expected interface. It doesn't mind if the transformations you need are easy or complex (*as you stated in note 1*).

So, I think you are better with adapter pattern, if I don't misunderstood your question.

Comment: it is not pure proxy pattern it is proxies have to implement specific interface.

Comment: There is a third case, called Protection Proxy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern#Possible_Usage_Scenarios - but in OP's question, it's written `more than one provider and each one have different interface` -- that is definitely the problem solved by `Adapter` as you say.

Comment: @BassemRedaZohdy You could provide Proxies to the Adapters. I would not make a hybrid design, as it's less clear to engineers who have learned the names and uses of the patterns. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201397/difference-between-the-adapter-pattern-and-the-proxy-pattern